# 2^32 bit or byte on 32-bit OS

Tags: byte, bit

All

I try to learn about memory paging.but I have a bit confused about memory address.

We say that 32-bit OS can address 4GiB memory.  We know 1 Byte = 8 Bit.

So what's the unit on 2^32 ?  4294967296 Bit?   or Bytes?  why?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can have 2^32 different memory addresses.

Each such address points at one byte (that is the smallest addressable memory unit).

So you can address 4GB (giga-bytes) of memory with 32 address bits.